# How Do I modify values in objects that is in a lodash grouped object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have a object created using [Lodash's groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) like this:

```
const GroupedData = {
  '01/02/2000': [{isChanged: true}, {isChanged: false}, {isChanged: false}],
  '02/02/2000': [{isChanged: true}, {isChanged: false}],
  '03/02/2000': [{isChanged: false}]
}
```

How do I change the isChanged boolean in all the objects to true? It is not a must to use lodash, but is there anyway to do it efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`_.mapValues()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mapValues) to map the values in your object. For each value (ie: array) in your object you can return a new array that is created by mapping (with `_.map()`), the current array value. You can use the map method to map each object to a new object with the `isChanged` property set to `true`, which you can do by merging a new object `{isChanged: true}` into the existing object with [`_.assign()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#assign). This approach will leave your original object as is, and return a new object with new array values/objects:

```js
const groupedData = {
  '01/02/2000': [{isChanged: true}, {isChanged: false}, {isChanged: false}],
  '02/02/2000': [{isChanged: true}, {isChanged: false}],
  '03/02/2000': [{isChanged: false}]
};

const res = _.mapValues(
  groupedData, 
  v => _.map(v, o => _.assign({}, o, {isChanged: true}))
);
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The same result can be achieved with vanilla JS, using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to map your values, and then using [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to rebuild it once mapped:

```js
const groupedData = {
  '01/02/2000': [{isChanged: true}, {isChanged: false}, {isChanged: false}],
  '02/02/2000': [{isChanged: true}, {isChanged: false}],
  '03/02/2000': [{isChanged: false}]
};

const res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(groupedData).map(([key, val]) => [
  key, 
  val.map(obj => ({...obj, isChanged: true}))
]));
console.log(res);
```

---

If you're fine with modifying the object in place, you could just use a regular [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to loop the keys of your object, which would be the most efficient, the lodash version of this is would be something like so:

```js
const groupedData = {
  '01/02/2000': [{isChanged: true}, {isChanged: false}, {isChanged: false}],
  '02/02/2000': [{isChanged: true}, {isChanged: false}],
  '03/02/2000': [{isChanged: false}]
};

_.forOwn(groupedData, arr => _.each(arr, obj => {
  obj.isChanged = true
}));
console.log(groupedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thanks for such a detailed answer!